# Refresh iScroll on click

Tags: refresh, iscroll

here is working [Demo](http://touchlist.koma.hr) if you put screen size to width:360x540 and click on title or date it opens but then you will see that scrolling isn't working.

I have try to setup callback function

> myScroll.refresh ()

after it opens even i have tried to destroy then build new scroll but then i get some errors.

In configuration of

> iScroll.js

i have put

> checkDOMChanges:true

but no help.

Comment: Does any body have idea about this problem?

Comment: I am searching for this solution for few days and i hoped that someone will have idea how to fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

In my project we faced same issue, my team solved the issue by adding timeout
code as follows:

```
/*  s  */
setTimeout(function(){
  iscrollName.refresh();
},300) // you can changed the interval until whats you want
/*  e  */
```